# Вылетает NullReference при парсинге json данных

Tags: c#, json

Я закрепил 2 скриншота.

На одном, показано, какой json приходит

На втором, во время отладки, заранее вылетает null, не могу понять почему

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой класс:

```
 public partial class SS
    {
        [JsonProperty("PackageSearchQuery")]
        public PackageSearchQuery PackageSearchQuery { get; set; }

    }

    public partial class PackageSearchQuery
    {
        [JsonProperty("Departures")]
        public Departure[] Departures { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Destination")]
        public Destination[] Destination { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("BeginDate")]
        public DateTimeOffset BeginDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("EndDate")]
        public DateTimeOffset EndDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("SelectedDate")]
        public DateTimeOffset SelectedDate { get; set; }

        public long DateRange { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Acc")]
        public long[] Acc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("PriceRange")]
        public dynamic[] PriceRange { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Guest")]
        public Guest Guest { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CurrencyId")]
        public long CurrencyId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Page")]
        public long Page { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Departure
    {
        [JsonProperty("Id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Label")]
        public string Label { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Destination
    {
        [JsonProperty("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DataId")]
        public long DataId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("TopDataId")]
        public long TopDataId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ParentDataId")]
        public long ParentDataId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("FullTitle")]
        public string FullTitle { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("TitleRu")]
        public string TitleRu { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ParentTitle")]
        public string ParentTitle { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ParentTitleRu")]
        public string ParentTitleRu { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Weight")]
        public long Weight { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Score")]
        public double Score { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ModelType")]
        public string ModelType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("HasAirport")]
        public bool HasAirport { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Priority")]
        public long Priority { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Guest
    {
        [JsonProperty("Adults")]
        public long Adults { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Children")]
        public dynamic[] Children { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class RoomQuery
    {
        [JsonProperty("RoomId")]
        public long RoomId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("MealId")]
        public long MealId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AccId")]
        public long AccId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("FlightNight")]
        public long FlightNight { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("FlightDate")]
        public DateTimeOffset FlightDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("LeftAllotmentStatus")]
        public long LeftAllotmentStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("LeftAllotmentBackStatus")]
        public long LeftAllotmentBackStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("IsReqular")]
        public bool IsReqular { get; set; }
    }
```

Еще раз кину в текстовом варианте json

```
{"PackageSearchQuery":{"Departures":[{"Id":2671,"Label":"Москва"}],"Destination":[{"Id":"Country3","DataId":3,"TopDataId":null,"ParentDataId":null,"FullTitle":"Россия (Russia)","Title":"Russia","TitleRu":"Россия","ParentTitle":null,"ParentTitleRu":null,"Weight":4,"Score":3490.5999999974056,"ModelType":"country","HasAirport":false,"Priority":1}],"BeginDate":"2020-07-19T00:00:00Z","EndDate":"2020-07-19T00:00:00Z","SelectedDate":"2020-07-20T00:00:00Z","DateRange":"0","Acc":[3],"PriceRange":[],"Guest":{"Adults":2,"Children":[]},"CurrencyId":0,"Page":1},"HotelDetailQuery":null,"RoomQuery":{"RoomId":0,"MealId":0,"AccId":0,"FlightNight":0,"FlightDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","LeftAllotmentStatus":0,"LeftAllotmentBackStatus":0,"IsReqular":false},"FlightQuery":null,"ReservationQuery":null}
```

Comment: А где основной класс - `Coral`, в который у вас идет десериализация?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ случайно название класса Сoral на SS заменил

Comment: Ок, а как у вас этот код вообще десериализовался? Что вы используете для десериализации?

Comment: Вот смотрите, берем популярную библиотеку JSON.NET, берем ваши классы, ваш JSON и пытаемся [десериализовать](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DuAFiN), получаем ошибку, почему? Да потому, что у вас в JSON есть null объекты, которые в классах у вас не поддерживают это, например `public long TopDataId { get; set; }` в JSON у вас `"TopDataId": null,`, а `long` типо не может быть NULL. По этому, это свойство должно быть как минимум Nullable типом (`public long? TopDataId { get; set; }`).

Comment: Использую Newtonsoft.Json, раньше нормально все работало, сейчас баг. Он уже заранее знает, что он будет null

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Все, понял, спасибо

Comment: Это можно обойти при помощи [настроек](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AguvTE), тогда да, ваш JSON будет успешно десериализироваться, но я не вижу у вас этих настроек. По этому для меня загадка, как вы десериализовали такое? Кстати заметьте, при добавление настроек, ваша строка успешно отдает результат.. Ай, моя невнимательность, у вас и падает на моменте десерилации... Тогда да, делаете Nullable или меняйте настройки (что не желательно).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в определении Destination TopDataId null для типа long а он не nullable там ещё ParentDataId ... Будьте внимательны с long и long?